# What do $\Bbb N^*$ and $\Bbb Z(p^n)$ mean in this paper?

Tags: group-theory, notation

There is a theorem:

[image]

in this paper: http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ78_01%2FS1446788700015548a.pdf&code=2ffd5c5100675caf83c2e95bce65491e

But there is no explanation of notations. What is $\Bbb N^\star$ and $\Bbb Z(p^n)$? Are they $\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$ and $\Bbb Z_{p^n}$?

Comment: A convention (systematically used in the French educating system, and sometimes elsewhere) is to denote by $\mathbb{N}$ non-negative integers, and $\mathbb{N}^*$ to mean $\mathbb{N}-\{0\}$, that is, positive integers. With the American convention to denote by $\mathbb{N}$ positive integers, the notation $\mathbb{N}^*$ is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In abelian group theory, it's customary to denote by $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ the Prüfer $p$-group (the $p$-torsion part of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a realization thereof).

The subgroups of this group form a chain:
$$
\mathbb{Z}(p^0)\subset\mathbb{Z}(p^1)\subset\mathbb{Z}(p^2)\subset
\dots\subset\mathbb{Z}(p^n)\mathbb{Z}(p^{n+1})\subset\dots\subset
\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)
$$
and the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}(p^n)$ is cyclic of order $p^n$ (for finite $n$).

The meaning of $\mathbb{N}^*$ should be explained by the clause *such that $p^lB=0$ holds for a nonnegative $l<n$*; this strongly suggests
$$
\mathbb{N}^*=\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}
$$

The notation $\mathbb{Z}(p^n)$ and $\mathbb{N}^*$ in the sense explained above is widely used in Fuchs' *Abelian Groups* cited in the references.

Comment: Yes $\Bbb Z_{p^n}$ is found: http://books.google.com/books?id=Vb38GspKia8C&pg=PA282#v=onepage&q&f=false but not $\Bbb N^*$

Comment: @user138171 I guess the authors of the paper consider the notation as folklore; about $\mathbb{N}^*$ in Fuchs' book I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that's the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

primary component means the subgroup of all elements whose order is a power of $p$ and yes $\mathbb Z(p^n)$ is $\mathbb Z$/$p^n$$\mathbb Z$

$N^*$ should be non negative integer.